# Neo4j how to retrieve List of Nodes by cypher query using Java driver

Tags: neo4j

```
    StatementResult result = graphBasicService.readStatement(query);
    while (result.hasNext())
    {
        Record record = result.next();
        // Values can be extracted from a record by index or name.
        System.out.println("nodes: "+record.asMap().values());
    }
```

As In above code example I am trying to retrieve node that has values {mobile, status} . Though on browser I get List, with above code I just get one value.(One mobile number).

More on I get results printed as

> mobile: [node<9>]

What does 9 denotes here? And how I can retrieve list of nodes to print mobile number.

In case you require query:

> MATCH (n :User {mobile:"9999999"}) -[r :CONTACT] -> (m :User
>   {withm:"true"}) - [r2:CONTACT] -> (n) return m

**Note:** graphBasicService is my custom method that executes above query.

**Question Summary:** I am trying to retrieve and print List of Nodes, and am unable to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any lists here. There's no `collect()` in your query, or any other function or procedure that would produce a list. You're just getting a stream of result records.

You'll get one node per record with this query, so if you want a list, you would either create a list outside the loop and add the node to the list within your loop, or, if you want to modify the query itself, use `RETURN collect(m) as users` (or, if you just want the numbers, `RETURN collect(m.mobile)`. If you did this, then you would get a single record back with a list of nodes (or mobile numbers).

Comment: Thanks I understood, collect will return list, but then how come query browser is showing same result with and without collect? That is confusing, as if query browser has shown wrong result I would have diverted towards query correction rather than looking on driver API. Any suggestions or remark on this?

Comment: No luck still Map size is same. Please check update in question - made a try with your suggestion.

Comment: There was problem with query as well - working as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing record by record, you can get all the data using list() at once and then process it.

```
 List<Record> recordList = result.list();
 for (Record record : recordList) { 
   //Parsing code here
 }
```

Refer this:
https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/1.0/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementResult.html#list--